# Accumulation Buffer using GLFW

Tags: opengl, buffer, glfw

I have to use Accumulation Buffer in my openGL project (DOF rendering), but it doesn't seem to work with the GLFW library. 
I move a camera properly on a circle, take 21 "shots" (10 to the left, 1 in the normal position, 10 to the right), add all of them to the accumulation buffer (multiplied by 1/21), and when I am in the "normal" position, I show the buffer. However, the image is just still, unblured, but rendering 21 times slower than before.
The main loop is:

```
    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {

    // GLFW initialisation
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        return -1;
    }
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_FALSE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 16);
    GLFWwindow* window;
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 800, 600, "DOF", NULL, NULL);
    if ( !window ) {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }   
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // check for errors
    GLenum err = glGetError(); 
    if( err ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", glewGetErrorString( err ) );
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // GLEW init
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum GlewInitResult;
    GlewInitResult = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != GlewInitResult) {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(GlewInitResult));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // main loop
    Game game;
    game.Init();
    Keyboard::KeyboardInit();
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClear(GL_ACCUM_BUFFER_BIT);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glAccum(GL_ACCUM, 1 / (game.getSteps() * 2 + 1)); // steps = 10
        game.nextStep(); //increments step by one
        game.Update();
        game.Redraw();
        if (game.getStep() == 1) {
            glAccum(GL_RETURN, 1);
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        }

        glfwPollEvents();

        calcFPS(2.0, "DOF", window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, you did neglect to request any accumulation buffer bits in your pixel format. Though in all likelihood this does not matter, because if you enumerate all of the pixel formats, the accumulation buffer is always non-zero on some platforms. What ***really*** matters here is that you have a core profile, which does not support accumulation buffers. About the best you could probably do is use the 16x MSAA you are currently using (which, by the way, is not supported by a lot of GPUs) to store 7 left images, 1 center and 7 right.

Answer (score 3):

Be advised that accumulation buffers are something from the past and are not accelerated on most consumer cards with modern OpenGL profiles; it's much more likely to be supported by professional grade cards.

Anyway, you have to request for a accumulation buffer to get one. But then you're asking for a *OpenGL-3.3 core* profile and this provides you something much better than accumulation buffers: Framebuffer Objects. Those are widely supported (if using the FBO extension even by very old hardware dating back to pre 2000) and allow for much more flexibility.

The usual approach is to:

1. Render the scene into a texture
2. Draw this texture with `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)` blending into an accumulation texture that has a HDR format (GL_RGB16 or similar) and the alpha value being 1/n with n being the amount of accumulation steps

You normally create two separate FBOs for this. Pseudocode

```
for step in DOF:
    glBindFramebuffer(scenedraw_FBO)
    draw_scene()

    glBindFramebuffer(accumulation_FBO)
    glBindTexture(…, scenedraw_texture)
    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE)
    glColor4f(1.,1.,1., 1./(float)count(DOF) )
    draw_fullscreen_textured_quad()
    glBindTexture(…, 0)
```

Instead of scaling with the alpha value you can also use a float texture format and use `glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)` blending. However float textures are not as widely supported.